# 1 file checks, other file checks too but have to be connected without changing variables

Tags: php

I am building a website where people need to go to 1 page. The page checks if something already has been done. If it hasn't done yet, it will load the page without redirecting. It will give the steps somebody has te do. After doing that, it will redirect the person to a other file. And check if it has been done and give a reward. Between those 2 request people can change variables. Or go directly to the second file. How can I make sure people don't skip the other file? I tought about using google recaptcha v2, but I want to get some advice from you guys first. Because I know that there are captcha solving websites (DeathByCaptcha etc.

I would be really thankful!

EDIT:
I already have made a vertification method. Where people will get a key at the first file. And the second file checks it. Before those 2 files, there is another file, that just sends the persons IP  tru session. Here it is:

```html
$GRFL = $_POST['amount'];
$OMFG = $_POST['username'];
$ip = GetIP();
$ip = md5(md5(md5(md5(md5(md5(md5(md5(md5(md5(md5($ip)))))))))));
if ($_SESSION['ip'] != $ip) {
    header('Location: '.$url);
    die();
} else {
    $query = md5($ip.md5(md5($GRFL.$OMFG.$ip).md5($OMFG)).$ip);
    $_SESSION['query'] = $query;
}
```

But I don't know if it is enough...

Comment: It's all about keeping state and checking state. Where you maintain that state is up to you (i.e. session, database, Redis, etc.)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I already have that by session. Check out the edit. Is that enough, or do I need more?

Comment: You ought to go read up on sessions and the `$_SESSION` variable

Comment: Calling `md5()` repeatedly does not improve it in any way.